# Just trying to insert a node and set the pointer in it to the next node C++

Tags: c++, insert, linked-list, nodes

I feel really silly asking this, as it seems really simple, but I just can't figure it out. All I want to do is set the node pointer to the next node in the list. The function is from a teacher, I wrote the body, so I don't want to mess with the head of the function.

```
void LList::insert(int num, int at)
{
    node* n = new node(num);
    if (!n) throw runtime_error("Can't allocate node!");

    if(!root || at == 0){
        // if empty list - new node is root…
        if (!root) root = n;
    }

    if(root){
        node* nextNode = new node(num);

        int numF = 0;
        for (node* t = root; t != NULL ; t = t->next){
            numF++;
            if(numF == at){
                n->next=t->next; 
                t->next=n;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: `node* nextNode = new node(num);` is entirely unused. Any reason its in this code? Also, `root = nullptr` isn't going to bode well for the current list if you're prepending a node to the beginning (at=0) and there is already one or more nodes present.

Comment: There's no need to check for null after every allocation attempt with `new`... a compliant new handler implementation will throw `bad_alloc` if it cannot allocate memory

Comment: Probably You need `n->next=t->next; t->next=n` to insert a new node, but the whole function looks a bit strange.

Comment: Oops, didn't mean to have that nextNode in there, I took it out just before putting this up

Comment: You would probably be shocked how much easier this is with [a pointer-to-pointer.](http://pastebin.com/67jfPBJD)

Comment: Thank you kestasx, that worked! And it does look weird because I'm not too good at coding and my stuff seems very thrown around

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you are using `n` for the new node to be inserted into the linked list (I'm inferring that it's a singly linked list from the existing code and class name), there are a few things you have to do off the top of my head:

1. Identify the existing member of the list after which the new node will be inserted.  You are making an attempt to do this already with that `for` loop, but in my opinion you may want to rewrite that as a `while` loop since you probably don't want it to keep iterating after the insertion position has been identified.  Alternately, you could short-circuit out of the `for` loop with a `break` once you've found the right place for insertion, but I don't like that for stylistic reasons.  :)
2. Set the newly inserted node's `next` pointer to the same location to which the `next` pointer of the node identified in #1.
3. Set the `next` pointer of the node identified in #1 to point at the new node, thus re-establishing the integrity of the chain.

Your code looks like it is attempting to do #2 and #3 out of order, which won't work.  You're obliterating the value of `t->next` before you've had a chance to point `n->next` at it.

Finally, you may need to define some behavior to which you can fall back in case you are adding to a position not already defined in the list (i.e. inserting into the fourth position of a linked list that currently has three elements).  You may need to re-jigger your loop to terminate when `t->next` is null rather than when `t` itself is null - otherwise you lose the hook to be able to connect the (currently) last element of the list to your new node.